# object Object is showing in td

Tags: javascript, jquery

when i tried to add multiselect below tr it is showing [object Object].

```js
var counter = 0;
$("#addjs").click(function () {
    var anotherselect = $('#s1').clone();
    anotherselect.attr('id', "s1" + counter);
    $('tr').last().after("<tr><td></td> <td>" + anotherselect + "</td> <td> third row</td> <td>test</td> <td></td> </tr>");
    $("#s1" + counter).dropdownchecklist();
    counter++;
});
```

it is working, if i do like below

```js
var counter = 0;
$("#addjs").click(function () {
    var anotherselect = $('#s1').clone();
    anotherselect.attr('id', "s1" + counter);
    $('tr').last().after(anotherselect);
    $("#s1" + counter).dropdownchecklist();
    counter++;
});
```

I need to append with tr and td without   [object Object] error

Comment: `anotherselect` is an object but you treat it as a string and concatenate with `+` which calls `anotherselect.toString()` which is `"Object object"`.  Use jQuery to add `anotherselect` with `append()` or such like

Comment: still i am getting same error

Comment: I think you need `$(anotherselect).val()` in the HTML you add

Comment: Do you have the plugin loaded for `.dropdownchecklist();`?

Comment: Can you share HTML as well? It would help.

Comment: @zer00ne  yes plugin dropdownchecklist is loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to be sure, not knowing what element `anotherselect` represents, but you should be able to use [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) and [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) to handle the fact that you're really concatenating a string:

```
var counter = 0;
$("#addjs").click(function () {
    var anotherselect = $('#s1').clone();
    anotherselect.attr('id', "s1" + counter);
    $('tr').last().after("<tr><td></td> <td>" + 
    // change just this part
    anotherselect.get(0).outerHTML + 
    "</td> <td> third row</td> <td>test</td> <td></td> </tr>");
    $("#s1" + counter).dropdownchecklist();
    counter++;
});
```

The jQuery [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) method will give you the actual DOM element that `anotherselect` represents and [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) will serialize it so you can include it in your string of markup.